# Files uploaded to s3 are missing content

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to upload a series of files to s3 from a pandas data frame. The code I am using to do that is shown below

```
import os

import boto3
import pandas as pd
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError

ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['KEY_ID']
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']


def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

    try:
        s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
        print("Upload Successful")
        return True
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credentials not available")
        return False
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return False


df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
description = df.description.iloc[50]
text_file = open(f"textfile.txt", "w")
text = text_file.write(description)
upload_to_aws("textfile.txt",'bucket-name',"test.txt")
text_file.close()
```

I am grabbing an element of the data frame that is stored as a string and writing it to a text file. That file is created locally without problems however the versions on s3 show up with no content.
[image: Image size 0B]

What about my code is causing this issue and how can I make sure the content is showing up? If there is a smarter way to approach this I would love to know.

Comment: Close the file after you write to it, ideally use `with` when working with files.

Comment: using the with statement did not fix the error. Should I edit the question to use that syntax?

Comment: You need to close after the write but before the upload. You added the close after the upload.

Comment: that is very true and very correct. That fixed the issue. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the close the file first so that the data is written to the file system.

```
with open(f"textfile.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(description)

#now the with block ends and calls close() on the file and it's written to disk    
upload_to_aws("textfile.txt",'bucket-name',"test.txt")
```

It can be done with flush() also if you'd want to keep the file open to write more but you don't need that here.

Comment: It was the other folks in the comments who gave all the info but I figured to put it together anyway. Glad to hear it was useful.

Comment: oops btw had an extra 'text =' there by accident, it didn't really hurt anything though but clearer without the cruft now